# How to add an app to run automatically on startup in Android 11 and later?

Tags: android

I want my program to notify me after turning on the phone, but unfortunately, from Android 11 onwards, it is not possible to use broadcast receiver boot complete. Thank you in advance for your answers.

I used broadcast boot complete and got no results

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.